# What is the correct way to run Docker Image that's linked with another image through docker-compose in another machine?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, image, docker, containers

I created a Dockerfile, google_book image, and docker-compose.yml that links mongo image in Windows. I tried moving the files to Mac and unloaded google_book image and tried to build docker-compose but it's giving me this error...

```
#7 0.790 npm ERR! code ENOENT
#7 0.791 npm ERR! syscall open
#7 0.792 npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/package.json
#7 0.792 npm ERR! errno -2
#7 0.793 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'
#7 0.793 npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
#7 0.794 npm ERR! enoent 
#7 0.802 
#7 0.802 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#7 0.802 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-08-31T02_03_54_164Z-debug.log
```

I've googled around and it seems like it's because I don't have the package.json (and other files as well) to properly build it.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Now I'm confused because I thought that the whole point of Docker images was to get rid of these dependencies so that other machines can use it and I wrongly thought that running docker-compose on a different machine would link the loaded image and mongo image gotten from the web together and run it on the Docker container which is not the case it seems like...

My question is, how do I go about running an image in another machine then bearing mind that another image (mongo in this case) needs to be linked up with google_book image?

Comment: Does the `docker-compose.yml` file have a `volumes:` block that replaces the entire `/usr/src/app` directory with a bind mount?  That would cause this problem; it means you can't run the application without having the source locally available, which defeats the point of Docker a little.  You can usually safely delete that `volumes:` block.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have two machines M1 and M2. M1 is the one where you have all the files and dependencies (package.json, etc.). You can use the above Dockerfile to build an image in M1. For example something like,

```
docker build -t myimage:1.0.0 .
```

You can push this image to dockerhub or a private docker repository of your choosing. Then you should be able to pull this image from M2. When you are running the docker-compose in M2, use this image in the Dockerfile instead of the previous Dockerfile you used to build the image.

For example,

```
FROM myimage:1.0.0

# add whatever things you want done on top of this image
```

Please note that you have to provide the proper tag of the image in the Dockerfile. Otherwise it might say that the image is not found.